# autocomplete with an arbitrary number of input fields on a page

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have this ajax autocomplete function that works on every input field with a class of .train. However, the suggestions that are being passed into the .suggest_q class are being displayed in every .suggest_q, next to each .train input field, and not just the .train field that is being used. I believe I am using the correct selectors as I am using 'this' instead of .train near the .click function but I am still having issues. I want this function to only work on the .suggest_q and .train classes that are being used by the user and to have the other ones not display any suggestions. What would be the best way to have the autocomplete function to work with the .train and .suggest_a that is being typed in?

here is my ajax code for adding new .train input fields:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 0;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><input type="text" name="train[]" autocomplete="off" class="train"  /><span class="suggest_q" id="suggest_q"></span><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove train</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

here is the ajax autocomplete code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".train").each(function(index, element) {
       $(".train").live("keyup", function() { 
        $(".suggest_q").html("");
            var train = $(this).val();   
            train = $.trim(train);
            if(train)
            {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "train_ajax_query.php",
                    data: "train="+train,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $(".suggest_q").html(msg);
                        $(".suggest_q ul li").mouseover(function() {
                            $(".suggest_q ul li").removeClass("hover");
                            $(this).addClass("hover");
                        })
                        $(".suggest_q ul li").click(function() {
                            var value   =   $(this).html();
                            $(element).val(value);
                            $(".suggest_q ul li").remove();
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

here is the HTML

```
<div id="p_scents">
    <input type="text" class="train" size="20" autocomplete="off" name="train[]" />
                <div id="suggest_q" class="suggest_q">

                </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your autocomplete code, you use a global selector. You need to save the selected elements and then use these variables.

```
//Changed the live call for an on call since live is deprecated.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#p_scents").on("keyup", '.train', function() { 
    //we save vars with the objects we want to work with.
    var selectedTrain = $(this);
    var selectedSuggest = $(this).siblings('.suggest_q');
    selectedSuggest.html("");
    var train = selectedTrain.val();   
    train = $.trim(train);
    if(train) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "train_ajax_query.php",
        data: "train="+train,
        success: function(msg) {
          //the variables here should still be valid, unless you start more than one ajax
          //call simultaneously.
          selectedSuggest.html(msg);
          selectedSuggest.find("ul li").mouseover(function() {
            // This can happen when the variable selectedSuggest is no longer valid
            //for example, when another try has been done on another .train
            $(this).siblings("li").removeClass("hover");
            $(this).addClass("hover");
          });
          selectedSuggest.find("ul li").click(function() {
            var value   =   $(this).html();
            //again, the vars can have changed here, since the click can be a long time 
            //after the event registration
            $(this).parents('.suggest_q').siblings('input').val(value);
            $(this).parents('.suggest_q').find("li").remove();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The code has not been tested, but should work. Leave comments if you find any error, i will edit.

Comment: jaudette, Thank you so much for the help! I have implemented your code but it's not working correctly. It still displays results in every .suggest_q div on the page and now when I click a suggested value, it doesn't add it to the input field.

Comment: jaudette, that fixed the clicking event, but when you click the value selected appears in all input fields.

Comment: @user1725473 I just noticed you use ids everwhere, ids should be unique. You should add classes instead.

Comment: Good catch! I just deleted the ids for suggest_q and train so now only classes exists...the problem still exists

Comment: @user1725473 see http://jsfiddle.net/8z6gx/2 seems to be working. But i have to simulate the list.